Flutter Error: Exception: Failed to load sertifikasi: type 'String' is not a substype of type 'int' of index
here is my code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_smarcerti/app/modules/sertifikasi/views/detail_sertifikasi_body.dart';
import 'package:mobile_smarcerti/app/modules/sertifikasi/views/detail_sertifikasi_page.dart';
import 'package:mobile_smarcerti/pages/upload_sertifikasi_dosen.dart';
import 'package:mobile_smarcerti/services/api_service.dart';

class SertifikasiBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const SertifikasiBody({super.key});

  @override
  __SertifikasiScreenState createState() => __SertifikasiScreenState();
}

class __SertifikasiScreenState extends State<SertifikasiBody> {
  late Future<List<dynamic>> _sertifikasiFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _sertifikasiFuture = ApiService().fetchSertifikasi();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Search',
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(145, 255, 249, 249),
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Container(
                  height: 54,
                  width: 48,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(145, 255, 249, 249),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_list),
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text("Filter Options"),
                            content: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                ListTile(
                                  title: const Text("Filter 1"),
                                  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                ),
                                ListTile(
                                  title: const Text("Filter 2"),
                                  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                ),
                                ListTile(
                                  title: const Text("Filter 3"),
                                  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: _sertifikasiFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                  } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                    return const Center(child: Text('No data available'));
                  } else {
                    final sertifikasis = snapshot.data!;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: sertifikasis.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final sertifikasi = sertifikasis[index];
                        return Card(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: const Icon(
                              Icons.library_books,
                              size: 35.0,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 94, 151),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              sertifikasi['nama_sertifikasi'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 94, 151),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => DetailSertifikasi(
                                    idSertifikasi: sertifikasi['id_sertifikasi'],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            trailing: const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                              size: 20.0,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 94, 151),
                            ),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

here is my api_service code
// lib/services/api_service.dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:mobile_smarcerti/app/utils/constant.dart';
import 'package:mobile_smarcerti/app/utils/dio_interceptors.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ApiService {
  late Dio _dio;

  ApiService() {
    _dio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: ApiConstants.baseUrl,
        connectTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        receiveTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 3),
        validateStatus: (status) {
          return status! < 500;
        },
      ),
    );

    _dio.interceptors.add(DioInterceptor());
  }

  Future<Response> get(
    String path, {
    Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
    Options? options,
  }) async {
    try {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final token = prefs.getString('auth_token');

      final response = await _dio.get(
        path,
        queryParameters: queryParameters,
        options: Options(headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          if (options?.headers != null) ...options!.headers!,
        }),
      );

      return response;
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      throw _handleError(e);
    }
  }

  Future<Response> post(
    String path, {
    dynamic data,
    Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
    Options? options,
  }) async {
    try {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final token = prefs.getString('auth_token');

      final response = await _dio.post(
        path,
        data: data,
        queryParameters: queryParameters,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            if (options?.headers != null) ...options!.headers!,
          },
        ),
      );

      return response;
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      throw _handleError(e);
    }
  }

  Exception _handleError(DioException e) {
    if (e.type == DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout) {
      return Exception('Connection timeout');
    }
    if (e.type == DioExceptionType.receiveTimeout) {
      return Exception('Unable to connect to the server');
    }
    if (e.type == DioExceptionType.unknown) {
      return Exception('Something went wrong');
    }

    return Exception(e.message);
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchSertifikasi() async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.get('/sertifikasis/');
      if (response.data['success']) {
        return response.data['data'];
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load sertifikasi');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load sertifikasi: $e');
    }
  }

I have tried by creating a new flutter project with just that certification feature and it works properly but somehow it doesn't work when I try on my main project
I've been trying to solve this problem for 3 hours and the result is still the same.
here is the error in my virtual phone:
Error: Exception: Failed to load sertifikasi: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

and here is the error in debug console:
D/EGL_emulation(17071): app_time_stats: avg=426.41ms min=6.15ms max=6485.81ms count=16
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(17071): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(17071): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
D/EGL_emulation(17071): app_time_stats: avg=28.53ms min=4.21ms max=433.69ms count=29


Don't forget to respond to specific answers to help the community know what is helpful or not, or there is something to clarify.

If the property idSertifikasi method from,
DetailSertifikasi(
idSertifikasi: sertifikasi['id_sertifikasi'], requires numerical value, are you sure that id_sertifikasi is a key to get the pure numerical values? Because you'll get an exception if it produces not numerical characters.

I found a mistake in my original answer, so I corrected it and included some clarifications for you to avoid a data type exception next time.

type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' generally faced when you try to access a value from a map or list where the key or index is expected to be of type int, but you're providing a String (or vice versa). In your code, the problem is likely with how the API response data is being parsed in the fetchSertifikasi method.
Possible issue can be:
In fetchSertifikasi, you're returning response.data['data'], assuming it contains a list of dynamic objects (like maps). However, in your main project, the data field might not have the expected structure, or some fields (e.g., id_sertifikasi) might not have the correct data type (e.g., being a String instead of an int).
Debuging steps
Step 1: Log the response from the API to see its exact structure and confirm data types.
Step 2: Ensure Consistent Data Types
If the API is returning id_sertifikasi as a String instead of int, you should modify how you handle this data.
Step 3: Check JSON Parsing
If you expect specific data types from the API, use a model class to parse and validate the JSON

I agree with logging the response from the api_service in order to understand if the api_service is properly transporting the expected data values.

Under the SertifikasiBody class,
Use the sertifikasi variable properly based on the expected generated value that your widget handles.
It should work as expected as long as there is no data decoding or some conversion needed before it finally touches the widget.
Like, for example, if the generated data coming from sertifikasis[index] does not conflict with the widget you're using if it is compatible with the data type the widget is expecting.
However, if sertifikasis[index] generates base64 data, this data will be used to attach with the Image.memory widget, even the variable you use is set to var sertifikasi = sertifikasis[index]; but since Image.memory only accepts Uint8List bytes, so you need to decode the data first into byte data.
Like this one:
Image.memory(
  base64Decode(sertifikasi['some_base64_data']),
),

The same applies to the Text widget: if you got an int value from your variable (i.e., originally from your api_service, or other sources), you need to refactor your way of attaching it into the widget with <variable>.toString() for it to work properly.
Moreover, if the specific widget you are using, particularly a custom widget, received a value of String (i.e., retrieved as an alphanumeric or word value from a certain source) but your widget expects a value of int (which is the root cause of your exception), you have to review your api_service to correct its data transfer, such as how it should transfer a data-type-specific data (separation between pure int or String, etc.).
Conclusion, one of the most important parts of handling data from your api_service is that you need to know what data type is needed by your widget. But you need to consider first if your data source, or api_service provides expected data values.
I hope it helps!

I've tried your suggestion but the result is still the same error.

Then the problem is the actual data that your api_service is transferring to your Flutter app. You need to make sure that the widget class, such as DetailSertifikasi only receives numerical, not alphanumeric or alphabet/non-numerical characters.

Take note that, if Flutter expects a specific data value type, if it is numerical or not, image data, etc. The data should be specific in form unless you set it up in the right way (i.e., you convert it, decode/encode, or parse it first before it goes to your widget). Remember that you need to see what your actual data is, so have you tried to log the data coming from your api_service?

You encountered the exception because it didn't get the type of data it should have.
